# How to enable BLOB-logging for a Node.js Api App on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage, azure-api-apps

I have a node.js api app on azure. I use `bunyan` to log every request to `sdtout`. How can I save and read the log files? I enabled BLOB-logging. The only thing that shows up in my storage is a bunch of csv-files. Here is an example:

```
| date                | level   | applicationName | instanceId | eventId            | pid   | tid | message
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
| 2017-05-17T14:21:15 | Verbose | myApp           | tae9d6     | 636306276755847146 | 13192 | -1  | SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - File.Copy
| 2017-05-17T14:21:15 | Verbose | myApp           | tae9d6     | 636306276756784690 | 13192 | -1  | SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - process
```

Where are my logs, that I printed to `stdout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Create file `iisnode.yml` in your root folder (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) if not exists.

2) Add the following lines to it.

```
loggingEnabled: true
logDirectory: iisnode
```

After that done, you can find logs in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode`.

For more info, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug#enable-logging.

Comment: Thank you very much. My `iisnode.yml` was called `issnode.yml`

Comment: Unfortunately these logs are web accessible. Why can MS not just route the node logs that you see in "Log Streaming" into the blob!?

Answer (score 0):

After above settings in iisnode.yml, the logs you see D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode are from BLOB storage or file system.