# Express + Node application deployed to Azure can't connect to CosmosDB/DocumentDB

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-cosmosdb

I created an app using Nodejs, express and DocumentDB and deployed it to Azure(App Service\Web App). Everything is working fine except it is not connecting to DocumentDB. It works fine in my local environment.

I am new to this environment so not sure what additional information can be provided.

[image]

Only difference between my local environment and azure is that I added following web.config because site was not starting

Comment: Is ssl enabled at your Azure database? If yes, then try connecting it by setting `ssl=true`

Comment: This might the issue. Where should I set ssl=true?

Comment: For `Error 500`, you need to enable and see detailed errors of your web messages. About how to enable logging of **stdout** and **stderr**, please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029083/how-to-enable-blob-logging-for-a-node-js-api-app-on-azure/44029658#44029658).

Answer (score 1):

This has been really frustrating last couple of days.

URI listed in CosmosDB settings is https://xxxxxxxxpoc5.documents.azure.com:443/

and URI that worked for me is https://xxxxxxxxpoc5.documents.azure.com/, without port number 443.

Note: Both URIs worked from my local system.

Comment: thanks JSP that solved my issue as well. I had copied 443 from a sample app and it worked localy but would not once deployed. Removing the 443 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you enabled IP Access Control in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com). If this is the case, then you'll need to add your current IP to allowed IPs list. See [Azure Cosmos DB firewall support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/firewall-support).

Comment: IP access control is not enabled. How can I check if config.js file is deployed correctly?