# Azure NodeJS App Not Working

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a NodeJS app on Azure. It works with the base URL (http://membershipwebapp.azurewebsites.net) and I get the expected results. The issue is when I try to run a database query, for example http://membershipwebapp.azurewebsites.net/counties. When I run this, I get 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.'

I've gone to my output console and only see a deprecation warning.

I'm able to connect to the database in SSMS. When I run my application locally and go to http://localhost:1337, I get 'localhost refused to connect'.

Here the config in my app:

```
    var config = {
            server: 'servername.database.windows.net',
            database: 'myDatabase',
            user: 'user',
            password: 'password',
            port: 1433
        };

var sql = require("mssql");
var connection = new sql.Connection(config);
```

Comment: Is your database there and available? Do you use the correct connection string? What happens when you run the application locally while you target the database in Azure?

Comment: I can connect to the database from SSMS.

Comment: The fact that you can connect to the database doesn't mean it's available to your application in Azure ;) Where is the database? Does the Web App have access to the database? Are you using the right connectionstring in your application? What happens when you run the application locally while you target the database in Azure?

Comment: Under connection Strings for the web app in my Azure portal, it has the info for my Azure database.

Comment: When I run it locally against the Azure database, I get 'localhost refused to connect'.

Comment: I'm afraid we're going to need more to go on, because based on the limited information you're giving us now we will probably not be able to help.

Comment: I've added some more details in my originally question.

Comment: Have you enabled TCP/IP for the connection from NodeJS? SQL Azure doesn't support connecting with Named Pipes.

Comment: No I haven't. How do I enable that? I'm pretty new to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an internal server error, you may want to enable `sdtout` and `sterr` logs for a Node.js app on Azure App Service to see what logs say. About how to do that you can refer to [How to enable BLOB-logging for a Node.js Api App on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029083/how-to-enable-blob-logging-for-a-node-js-api-app-on-azure/44029658#44029658)

To connect to Azure SQL Database by using [mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) moudle, we need to add `encrypt: true` in options.

```
var config = {
    server: 'servername.database.windows.net',
    database: 'myDatabase',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    port: 1433,

    options: {
        encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
    }
}
```

Also notice that, if you access Azure SQL Database from your local computer, you'll need to add the IP address of the computer to allowed IPs list as below via the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

[image]