# authentication with Xamarin. Android and Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client Microsoft provider error

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I had a code that worked unlit few days ago: this is an xamarin.android activity code

```
[Activity(Label = "AuthSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button login;
    //Mobile Service Client reference
    private MobileServiceClient client;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL and key
        client = new MobileServiceClient("https://XXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net");

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        login = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonLoginUser);
        login.Click += onLoginClick;

    }

    private async void onLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load data only after authentication succeeds.
        if (await Authenticate())
        {

        }
    }

    // Define a authenticated user.
    private MobileServiceUser user;
    private async Task<bool> Authenticate()
    {
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            // Sign in with Microsoft login using a server-managed flow.
            user = await client.LoginAsync(this,
                MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
            CreateAndShowDialog(string.Format("you are now logged in - {0}",
                user.UserId), "Logged in!");

            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(ex, "Authentication failed");
        }
        return success;
    }


    private void CreateAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title)
    {
        CreateAndShowDialog(exception.Message, title);
    }

    private void CreateAndShowDialog(string message, string title)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.Create().Show();
    }
}
```

i did all the instruction in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users).
the LoginAsync redirect me to the Microsoft login page, i am able to authenticate and after a successful authentication i get this error : "the page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occured"

i am working with 3.1 azure sdk version

Comment: What's your mobile app backend, Node.js or c# ? I would recommend that you could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount` via your browser to isolate this issue. Or if your app has enabled restrict permissions to authenticated users, you could provide your app name, then I would check with it for more detailed error.

Comment: my backend is web api c#. i tried to access the url with app name :  https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback
and had an error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed that you could follow the steps below to troubleshoot this issue.

**For Node.js backend**

You could leverage [App Service Editor](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/App-Service-Editor) or [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) for create the `iisnode.yml` file under root folder (D:\home\site\wwwroot) if not exists. Then add the following settings for [enable logging to debug a Node.js web app in azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug#enable-logging):

```
loggingEnabled: true
logDirectory: iisnode
```

Additionally, here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029083/how-to-enable-blob-logging-for-a-node-js-api-app-on-azure/44029658#44029658) about enable node.js logging, you could refer to it. Also, for more details about kudu and app service editor, you could refer to [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx).

**For C# backend**

you could edit `App_Start\Startup.MobileApp.cs` file and configure the `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` as follows for capturing the error details:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

For a simple way, you could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name}` via the browser, then check the detailed error message for locating the specific error.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your address, I checked your app and found I could log with my Microsoft Account via the browser. Then I checked with your table endpoint and found the follow error:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

> message: "An error has occurred.",
>   exceptionMessage: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. **The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.** (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, **error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation**. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)",
>   exceptionType: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",

As I known, when following the quickstart to create the data store for your backend, downloading the C# backend, then deploy the backend to moible app. At this point, your created connection string via azure portal would not be exposed to your ASP.NET application, and the default connection string would use the localdb, you need to edit the `Web.config` file before deploying to azure mobile app as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MS_TableConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:{your-sqlserver-name}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={db-name};User ID={user-id};Password={password}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Or configure the connection string when deploy your app to azure mobile app via VS as follows:

[image]

Comment: added the 
`HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;`
but still getting the same error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: I just followed the tutorial about [How to configure your App Service application to use Microsoft Account login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication), then I could access `https://brucechen-mobile.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount` and logged successfully.  Based on the known description, I could not locate this issue.

Comment: I assumed that you could set "Action to take when request is authenticated" to "Log in with Microsoft Account" on the "SETTING > Authentication / Authorization" of your mobile app, then provide your app name, then I would dig into this issue on my side.

Comment: Moreover, I recommend that you could create a new mobile app and try to check whether you could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name}` via the browser successfully to isolate this issue.

Comment: Hi, the app is a sample app so i can give you her  [address](https://testauth123.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount)

Comment: Based on your address, I could log with my MSA and I could access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` via the browser to retrieve my logged info. Have you changed some settings?

Comment: I rechecked your app, and found the issue may due to the sql connection string, you could see my updates and check with your mobile app.

Comment: everything started to work again :) 
i believe there was an internal error at azure and it is fixed.
@Bruce - MSFT Thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been solved. Any concerns, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a problem in azure or in Microsoft authentication.
after two days of frustration everything just started to work again!!

Comment: The authentication for your mobile app is ok, but I found the table api could not work as expected. Could you access `https://testauth123.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0` successfully via your browser?