# Node Js RestFull API on Azure,Returns HTTP Error 500.1001 - Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed my nodeJs RESTFull API with MySQL, on azure using Dropbox.
On console i have seen logs that application started listing and database is connected. thus lines are from my code which i have logged using console.log();
When I request for my API/Resource, I get 500 ERROR massage from server. I searched a lot to solve this issue but am not able to solve this one.

I have added app setting with web.config sharing snapshot
[image: App settings]

i am using web.config sample from git hub [web.config](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps)

and my general settings look like this 
[image]

and the last thing logs from azure

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 

    <head> 
    <title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.1001 - Internal Server Error</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    <!-- 
    body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
    code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
    .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
    pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
    ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
    ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
    fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
    .summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
    legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
    legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
    font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
    a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
    a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
    h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
    h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
    h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
    h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
    }#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
    color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
    }#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
    .summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
    .content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
    }#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
    }#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
    }#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
    background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
    font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
    }#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
    table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
    td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
    th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
    thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
    }#details-right th{width:20%;} 
    table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
    .highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
    .clear{clear:both;} 
    .preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
    --> 
    </style> 

    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="content"> 
    <div class="content-container"> 
    <h3>HTTP Error 500.1001 - Internal Server Error</h3> 
    <h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4> 
    </div> 
    <div class="content-container"> 
    <fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
    <ul>    <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.</li>    <li>IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.</li>     <li>The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.</li>   <li>The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.</li> </ul> 
    </fieldset> 
    </div> 
    <div class="content-container"> 
    <fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
    <ul>    <li>Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.</li>     <li>Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.</li>  <li>Verify the permissions for the DLL.</li>    <li>Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.</li>  <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
    </fieldset> 
    </div> 

    <div class="content-container"> 
    <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
    <div id="details-left"> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;iisnode</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000002</td></tr> 

    </table> 
    </div> 
    <div id="details-right"> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://API:80/app.js</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 

    </table> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div> 
    </fieldset> 
    </div> 

    <div class="content-container"> 
    <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
    This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error. 
    <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,1001,0x00000002,9200">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
    <p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> 


    </fieldset> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you post the API that you are trying to call?. I suspect something went wrong in your API.

Comment: You want to look into server.js,routers ands Dals? the API workes fine on my local box .even i used azure mysql database(the one i have created on my azure account) with my locally running NodeRest.

Comment: I would like to check the server.js. No need if it's working in your local machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 things:

1. You should use `process.env.PORT` for handling the named pipe port in Azure App Service. See [Listen additional port Microsoft Azure Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424405/listen-additional-port-microsoft-azure-nodejs).
2. If #1 didn't solve your problem, you'll need to enable logging of stdout and stderr for further troubleshooting. See [How to enable BLOB-logging for a Node.js Api App on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029083/how-to-enable-blob-logging-for-a-node-js-api-app-on-azure/44029658#44029658)

Comment: Thanks! added process.env.PORT and its worked for me. Thank you so much for the help! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with my Azure web app using NextJS and Express server. Even though, I was using `process.env.PORT` in my code, I was still getting above mentioned error. After spending some time I found that the issue was on this line in server.js:

**Wrong**

```
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
```

**Correct**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

I am pasting my answer for anyone else facing the same issue when using custom server for NextJS. The point to remember is that Azure uses pipe like `\\.\pipe\xx-xx-xx-xx` instead of port number.

Comment: Thank you. You have a good point. In some tutorials this isn't covered. +1

Comment: this was clutch