# Error 500.1001 when deploying NodeJS API to Azure AppService

Tags: node.js, api, azure

In a simple nodeJS api, based on Express, I have a generic catch all for unhandled routes (app.get('*', (req, res) => { console.log("routing"); }) ).
When I try any route, I see the request coming through, but then it ends with an error 500.

I checked the logs, the logStream, etc. but I cannot find useful hints. 
Does anyone have idea of what's going on?

Thanks in advance,
G.

Comment: Enable dev errors in `iisnode.yml` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug, if that doesn't help, post the full app.js.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your app is listening on the wrong port when running on Azure App Service. See my earlier answer here: [Node Js RestFull API on Azure,Returns HTTP Error 500.1001 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458697/node-js-restfull-api-on-azure-returns-http-error-500-1001-internal-server-erro/45476225#45476225).