# Node.js Azure Web App Windows 500.1001 Error

Tags: node.js, azure

I have an Azure Web App on Windows, which runs iisnode to communicate with my Node app and I get a 500 error with a 1001 substatus. It seems as though IIS doesn't seem to be getting a response from Node. I've set up NODE_ENV and PORT variables under the Application Settings. I've also stripped this down to a Node Hello World application in order to minimize the variables. Node picks up the PORT variable and starts up using the proper port, as I know because I see the std out stating that the app started on the port specified. However, when I try any request, Node never appears to actually receive the request from iisnode. I get nothing if I try to console.log a message and I do not see any exceptions, which I would expect to be the case if it's on the response side of things. I've got other app services set up the same way, which appear to be working fine. I try to deploy the code from one of those and I get the same behavior.

I'm trying to use the following code for the most basic of tests

```
    var http = require('http');

    // Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
    var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
      console.log('Getting Response');
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.end("Hello World\n");
    });

    var port = process.env.PORT || '3003';
    server.listen(port);

    // Put a friendly message on the terminal
    console.log("Server running on port " + port);
```

I get the response `Server running on port 8080`, which leads me to believe the server starts up fine. However, I just get the friendly 500.1001 response in a browser. Any ideas about what could be causing this when it appears, from my perspective, to be set up the same as many other sites we have that are working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Web Apps only supports Port 80 for HTTP and Port 443 for HTTPS traffic. To aviod this error you need to remove PORT variable setting from **Application Settings** because Azure has passed a port in the variable `process.env.PORT` and it is not really a port number but a pipe like `\\.\pipe\(guid...)`. See [Node Js RestFull API on Azure,Returns HTTP Error 500.1001 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458697/node-js-restfull-api-on-azure-returns-http-error-500-1001-internal-server-erro/45476225#45476225).

Comment: So this works, but is this a recent change? I'm not sure why all of my other Web Apps work by specifying the Node port in the same way. Basically, I'm not sure how those other ones work now.