# Azure Webapp : What is the correct web.config in this case?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, iisnode

We are currently having some troubling in deploying a Node.js application on a Windows WebApp and we suspect that the problem is in the web.config file.

Here is Project Directory Structure:

[image]

We are using the default web.config with a few changes:
The application file is **app.js** and the public folder is **dist/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="dist{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    
    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Currently, the IIS Rewrite module is adding **dist/** to the URL, like so: http://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/dist/

And we have an iisnode error message:

> HRESULT: 0x2
>
> HTTP status: 500
>
> HTTP subStatus: 1001
>
> HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

I tried checking the Failed Request Tracing logs but no failed request was logged.

Could someone tell me what is happening in my case ?

---

### EDIT:

I decided to start back from scratch and created a new Web app.

I built the node.js app with the kudu console and (using the same web.config) the server now fetches correctly the *index.html* file in **dist/**.

So far so good, and we correctly land on the login page.

The problem now is that iisnode fails to process the POST request with the user credentials.

As Julien suggested, I tried changing the virtual directory of the app and had different errors:

1st case:

**Virtual directory:** /
**Path:** site\wwwroot
**Error**: The same iisnode error as the above

2nd case:

**Virtual directory:** /
**Path:** site\wwwroot\dist
**Error**: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Any thoughts on that ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your `web.config` is correct.

You can try replacing the content of app.js with the following minimal Node.js app to see if it works.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Azure');
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Important: use `process.env.PORT` as the port in your script when it runs on Azure Web Service.

Comment: Hi Aaron, yes it does work with that minimal Node.js app

Comment: Well, can you please edit your question to include your app.js?

Comment: Or you can enable logging of stdout and stderr for further troubleshooting. About how to do that see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029083/how-to-enable-blob-logging-for-a-node-js-api-app-on-azure/44029658#44029658).

Comment: Yes, you need to use process.env.PORT

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are pushing your App to web app, you can try to:

- Use the PROJECT environment variable to specify that your app is in the dist folder, as explained [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-inplace-and-without-repository).
- Define a virtual directory in the web app settings to specify that the root folder of your application is site\wwwroot\dist. You can find a JSON example of configuration [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs/blob/08470843be3fa0b558a0c9acb02c8a429e87d67a/azuredeploy.json#L114) or use the Application Settings blade in the Azure portal.

Hope this helps

Julien

Comment: Hi Julien,
I had a problem building the app on Azure where it couldn't find **./node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.css** for some reason.
So I started back from scratch and was able to build.
Now I have a different error and edited the question.